# Javascript with multithreading?

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, web

I am coming from a desktop application background, when I am learning Javascript, it is really difficult to understand the threading mechanism in Javascript.

For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn1").click(function(){
        for (var i = 0 ; i < 100000 ; i ++){
            $("#loop1").html(i);

        }
    });

    $("#btn2").click(function(){
        for (var i = 0 ; i < 100000 ; i ++){
            $("#loop2").html(i);

        }
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

Loop 1 : <p id="loop1"></p>
<button id="btn1">Button 1</button>
<br/><br/><br/>

Loop 2 : <p id="loop2"></p>
<button id="btn2">Button 2</button>

</body>
</html>
```

When I click on the button 1, the browser hang, so button 2 will not be responsive when I click it. Usually in desktop application, I will post the looping into background thread. But how am I going to do that in Javascript? Or what is the best way in handling long processing in Javascript?

---

edited :

the code below does not work, but not sure why.

```
$("#btn1").click(function(){

        setTimeout( function(){
            for (var i = 0 ; i < 100000 ; i ++){
                $("#loop1").html(i);

            }
        }
        , 0);
    });
```

Comment: Read this - http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/tutorials/introducing-html-5-web-workers-bringing-multi-threading-to-javascript.html#fbid=pjvP9hIpB6g

Comment: Also, http://www.sitepoint.com/multi-threading-javascript/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As previous answers already stated, **WebWorkers** are Javascript's only option for *multi-threading*. Unfortunately, there's no hope if you want to do DOM modifications.

What most people forget is when you call functions with `setTimeout` and `setInterval` **the UI does not freeze and still receives updates**.

```
function btnClickHandler() {
    setTimeout(doStuff, 1); // prevent UI freeze
}

function doStuff() {
    // do your stuff here
}
```

In your case:

```
var i, interval;

$("#btn1").click(function(){
    i = 0; // reset i

    // create interval
    interval = setInterval(btn1Handler, 1); // run btn1Handler every 1ms
});

function btn1Handler() {
    $("#loop1").html(i);

    if(i++ >= 100000) {
        // cancel the interval
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your example is awesome. It works perfectly. I have edited my question, before you added this example, I misunderstood your meaning and so I came out with the idea above, do you know why the code (in edited area) in my question does not work?

Comment: I am getting confused that, the behavior of setinterval and settimeout really so similar to create new thread. But everyone saying javascript is single threaded. I am curious how setinterval and settimeout did the magic?

Comment: because `setTimeout` and `setInterval` is time-based, they do not block the script so it is resumed. I do suggest however to use the interval as loop instead of running the entire loop inside a timeout. After a timeout or interval handler, the UI is updated. If you would loop inside an timeout/interval handler, it will still freeze the UI.

Comment: By the way, it would help if you would save `$("#loop1")` in a variable (`var $loop1 = $('#loop1');`) *before* you start the loop. Javascript will have to traverse through the DOM until it finds the element. If you do that before your loop, it only needs to traverse once, instead of 100,000 times ;) Little things like that can really influence your performance.

Comment: Here's a performance test of previous comment: http://jsperf.com/jquery-predefine-vs-reselect

Answer (score 2):

There is NO multithreading natively in Javascript.

Some techniques try to implement multi threads in the HTML5 spec ([WebWorkers](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/tutorials/introducing-html-5-web-workers-bringing-multi-threading-to-javascript.html#fbid=OJpujR1p6iK)), others try to implement it in javascript itself, but the base spec (ECMA) is single threaded.

You could just have searched on Google..

Comment: "There is NO multithreading natively in Javascript." How are WebWorkers not multi-threaded or not native?

Comment: That's not part of the ECMA spec, but an extension to the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Apart if you use [web workers](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/) (and they can't directly change the DOM), there is only one user javascript thread in your browser.

Events are stacked until your function returns. You can'd have two long running operations changing the DOM in parallel.